# Why Default C# Classes(written by Microsoft) don't obey the same C# rules as the classes written by a coder

Tags: c#

My Question is if I don't have a default constructor in `Class A`(which is a base class and has other 2 or 3 non-default constructors) , how could I run a non-default constructor in `Class B` which is derived from `Class A`.

But I have seen this doesn't hold true with Default C# classes, I was working with value providers in asp.net mvc and came across a class called `FormValueProvider`  which is derived from it's base class `NameValueCollectionValueProvider`.

`FormValueProvider` has only one constructor which has a parameter of type ControllerContext.
And it's base class `NameValueCollectionValueProvider` has two constructors one with two parameters of type `NameValueCollection` and `CultureInfo` respectively and other one with three parameters two of which are type `NameValueCollection` and the 3rd is type `CultureInfo.`

How can I instantiate **`FormValueProvider`** class with it's sole parametrized constructor when 
**`NameValueCollectionValueProvider`** doesn't have a default constructor. Why this rule is there for a programmer who writes his own code not applicable for default C# classes written by Microsoft.

Comment: Are you sure? You know you can call any constructor on the base class from any constructor on the derived class right? Most likely the constructor on the derived class is just doing that - chaining the construction call

Comment: MVC is open source so I recommend you look at that to see what it is doing. Your description doesn't indicate it is doing anything special, it is either calling its base class constructor using default properties or those from the `ControllerContext`, or it is calling an internal constructor not visible from outside the assembly.

Comment: There is no requirement for a default constructor. I rarely have a default constructor on service classes.

Comment: @user2864740 I do know that buddy, but if you really try to understand what I said. I can't see something like base:() in the derived class when I went to see the definition of the derived and it's base class so that was the whole point of confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Because they call them using `this` and `base` respectively.

For example, this constructor on the `FormvalueProvider` calls another constructor on `FormValueProvider`:

```
public FormValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
           : this(controllerContext,
             new UnvalidatedRequestValuesWrapper(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Unvalidated()))
```

Then that one calls the constructor on `NameValueCollectionValueProvider`:

```
internal FormValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext, IUnvalidatedRequestValues unvalidatedValues) 
             : base(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form, 
                    unvalidatedValues.Form, 
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Note that the second constructor is `internal`.. which means you won't be able to call that particular overload. What is happening here is that they are providing *default values* for the particular overloads, which means you don't have to specify them for them to make it to their destination.

The documentation for the `base` keyword is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx

Comment: I do know about base and this keywords and how do we use them in coding but as everybody who answered here says that all this is not visible unless you decompile the assembly. So that was the point of my confusion. But still thanks for the info you gave on this forum.

Comment: No worries. Its true that it can seem like a bit of wizardry from the outside. It never hurts to dig a little bit though :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such rule in C#, you can inherit from a base class with a non-default constructor.  For your derived class to work its constructors would have to call the base classes constructors using the [`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword.

So you could implement a class hierarchy like this:

```
class Employee {
    public Employee(string title) {}
}

class Manager: Employee {
    public Manager() : base("Manager") {}
}
```

So `Manager` can inherit from `Employee` and have a different constructor - as long as `Manager` calls a valid constructor on the `Employee` class.

Comment: I do know that buddy, but if you really try to understand what I said.  I can't see something like base:()  in the derived class when I went to see the definition of the derived and it's base class sp that was the whole point of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible that those classes use `internal` constructors. For example:

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    internal BaseClass() {}

    protected BaseClass(String myString) 
    {
        /* do some stuff */
    }
}

public class ChildClass 
{
    public ChildClass()
        : base() 
    {
        /* do some stuff */
    }
}
```

If the constructor is `internal`, then it would only be visible to objects within that same namespace (such as it's child class). Unless you decompiled the code from the .NET library, you, as a developer, would never see it.